# Magnetic circuit: What is the cross section area I need to use?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am struggling with this magnetic circuit.
[Magnetic circuit of a coil with moving part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C07LX.png)

What is the equivalent cross section area I need to use to find the magnetic flux?

Should I use $A_c$ for the moving part or $A_g$? Or should I use $A_g$ for the stationary core? $A_g=A_c(1-\frac{x}{X_0})$

Which solution is correct?

\begin{align}
\phi=\frac{NI}{R_c+2R_g+R_p}=\frac{NI}{\frac{l_c}{\mu {\color{Red}{A_c}}}+2\frac{g}{\mu_0 A_g}+\frac{l_p}{\mu {\color{Red}{A_g}}}} \\\\
\phi=\frac{NI}{R_c+2R_g+R_p}=\frac{NI}{\frac{l_c}{\mu {\color{Red}{A_c}}}+2\frac{g}{\mu_0 A_g}+\frac{l_p}{\mu {\color{Red}{A_c}}}} \\\\
\phi=\frac{NI}{R_c+2R_g+R_p}=\frac{NI}{\frac{l_c}{\mu {\color{Red} {A_g}}}+2\frac{g}{\mu_0 A_g}+\frac{l_p}{\mu {\color{Red} {A_g}}}}
\end{align}

I have used FEMM to understand how flux lines behave. It is not clear.
[Magnetic flux lines and flux density for two positions of the plunger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5nWP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reluctance of the core has nothing to do with $A_g$, so
$$R_c = \frac{l_c}{\mu A_c}. $$

The two overlap of the core and the plunger is $A_g$, so you would write
$$R_g = \frac{g}{\mu_0 A_g}$$
The right value would probably be some average of $A_c$ and $A_g$.

Note that the reluctances of the plunger and the gap are in parallel, so you would write
$$ R_p = \left[\left(\frac{l_p}{\mu A_p}\right)^{-1}+ \left(\frac{l_p}{\mu_0 (A_c - A_g)} \right)^{-1} \right]^{-1} $$
where $A_p$ is the area of the plunger. If $\mu \gg \mu_0$ and the plunger isn't too far out, this can be simplified to
$$ R_p = \frac{l_p}{\mu A_p}. $$

The truth is the correct areas to use aren't always obvious: simple models like this are useful for quick hand calculations but don't always predict the actual results very accurately. For example, in this case the reluctance $\frac{l_p}{\mu A_p}$ of the plunger may not be accurate if the plunger is very thin: then the correct area would be some average of $A_p$ and $A_g$. Note that this analysis neglects also neglects fringe fields and uses a rather simple equation for the core reluctance, so don't expect it to match up exactly with your simulation results.

Comment: $A_g$ is the overlapping cross section area. Please note $x_0=0$. So, you are suggesting I should use the entire $A_c$ for the stationary core, and $A_g$ for the plunger and air gaps? This makes a lot of sense to me. But, it did not match author's solution. That is why I am asking this question. The author (Fitzgerald: Electric Machinery) seems to think the equivalent cross section area of the plunger is equal to that of the core, $A_c$. Any comments?

Comment: Clarification: When plunger is fully retracted (completely in), $x=x_0=0$.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If the plunger is sufficiently thick, you would use the actual cross section area of the plunger. This assumes it is thick enough that the field is able to redistribute itself across the cross section area of the plunger, but it isn't obvious that this happens, otherwise the correct area may be closer to $A_g$. Perhaps the plunger area is the same as $A_c$ and this is what Fitzgerald is thinking? I don't know why he would use $A_c$ otherwise.